# HippoCMS translated documents with shared fields

Tags: internationalization, hippocms

I am evaluating HippoCMS and am trying to model a schema of `Venue`s. I want to model a document that has non-translatable features such as `telephoneNumber` and `emailAddress`, plus translatable features such as `description`.

How do I model this in HippoCMS? How do I ensure that the non-translated fields are shared between the different translations, to avoid each translated document having its own copy of a value. Obviously no matter which language you are reading a site in, the `telephoneNumber` shouldn't change.

The only way I have found for the moment is to create a document called `Venue` and another document called `VenueTranslation`. `Venue` would contain the `telephoneNumber` and `VenueTranslation` would contain its description and a link back to the `Venue` document. There would then be `VenueTranslation` documents for each language.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

That could work, but you will run into usability issues. I'd say it depends on how many venues you plan to enter into the system, how many languages you are targeting, and, in the end, how keen are your CMS users to pick the right `Venue` document for every `VenueTranslation` corresponding to a language. I can see how this will quickly become error prone and cumbersome, but I don't have the numbers.

Regarding the final question, it's not correct nor incorrect: it's just that since the granularity of the translations in Hippo is at the document level and not at the field level, you have to do it this way. Your model makes sense but is not well supported in the CMS. This use case is trivial in a CMS that supports the notion of translatable field.